# Wamp MySQL PhpMyAdmin Remote access configuration issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, remote-access

I am trying to give remote access for my phpmyadmin, i had put [wamp online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4ySR.png) as well and everthing working fine in my localsystem.

[image: Wamp Online]

I can access my PhpMyAdmin from IP4 address now as well as localhost. But using the same IP4 address from remote i am not able to connect to my Phpmyadmin.

I get error as : CONNECTION_TIMEOUT

Here is what the configuration looks like in : `c:/wamp/apps/phpMyAdmin4.3.12/`

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpMyAdmin4.3.12/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

And in `httpd.conf` file configured as :

```
Listen 192.168.3.170:81
Listen 0.0.0.0:81
Listen [::0]:81
```

From remote system, ping is also working which shows there is no firewall blocking.

[image: Ping to 192.168.3.170]

Is there any configuration setup missing w.r.to port 81 as port 80 is been used by `nginx` or am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `c:/wamp/apps/phpMyAdmin4.3.12/` to this :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpMyAdmin4.3.12/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all

  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    #Require local
    Require all granted                   <-- moved access control
  </IfDefine>

  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
  </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

If you notice there are 2 `IfDefine` statements in this file, its there so this config will work with either Apache 2.2.x or Apache 2.4.x. You just needed to add your change to the access requirements to the relevant section. I assume yo are using Apache 2.4.?

Comment: I am using apache version : 2.4.9. Still no luck, its the same error :(